# Where should you place the class that extend Application in jax.rs

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven

The code below is the new project I made in netbeans but I used the MAVEN as project type. Since i want to create a folder structure like below

```
+ com.kixortillan.mavenproject1
---+com.kixortillan.mavenproject1.controllers
---+com.kixortillan.mavenproject1.models
```

I do not know where to put the class that extends Application. I tried putting it in com.kixortillan.mavenproject1 and a test controller in com.kixortillan.mavenproject1.controllers but it show error 404

The url I am calling is http://localhost:8080/mavenproject1/services/test

ApplicationConfig Class

```
package com.kixortillan.mavenproject1;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("services")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(com.kixortillan.mavenproject1.controllers.TestResource.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Test Controller

```
package com.kixortillan.mavenproject1.controllers;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author NOC
 */
@Path("test")
public class TestResource
{

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of TestResource
     */
    public TestResource()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of com.kixortillan.mavenproject1.controllers.TestResource
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String getXml()
    {
        //TODO return proper representation object
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of TestResource
     * @param content representation for the resource
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public void putXml(String content)
    {
    }
}
```

Very much appreciated if you could give me a much details tutorial on how things work in jax.rs

Comment: What does _"I cannot make it work"_ mean? Are you getting errors/exceptions? The class alone looks fine. It's purpose is to configure the JAX-RS application programatically. With this, you don't need any web.xml

Comment: Can you give details about the error? What URL are you using to access the web service? Also, the the inherited class can be used to specify the classes that you want to expose as REST services. Otherwise, the JAX RS runtime will scan the classpath.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: I need to know if it is possioble to create a rest client project using jax.rs using maven. Because I want maven to handle the dependencies of the project.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work". That is not a clear enough definition for us to help you. And FYI, the location of the class is fine

Comment: It show error 404. It cannot successfully find the services/test resource

Comment: Everything looks fine except that you are throwig an exception in the method that is going to get hit. This should not produce a 404 though. Other than that, the problem lies somewhere else in something you're not showing/telling us, like deployment, environment, packaging.

Comment: I believe so too :) Here is how I made the project 1. Create New Project in Netbeans 2. Create a folder in ../src/main/java/com/kixortillan/mavenproject1 (controllers and models folder) 3. Right click project, select New Restful web services from patterns, I set it to be in the cotrollers package. 4.) 2 files will be created, the ApplicationConfig.java and my TestResource.java (both under controllers folder) 5. When I try to run , it shows error 404

Comment: Is there a way for me to debug the routing of url's? My primary goal is to create a model and cotroller folder. But whenever I do this routing seems to fail because the resource cannot be found anymore. When I try to stick with the default directory (meaning ApplicationConfig and TestResource is in the default package) it works.

Comment: If this is a Maven project, when you build it, if you don't change the name, the .war file should be something like `yourproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. This should be the path you use in the URL, instead of just `yourproject`.

Comment: You can change the name by adding `<build><finalName>yourproject</finalName></build>` to your pom.

Comment: Hmm.. never mind, I did see the comment about it works in the default package

Comment: do you have resource that I may refer to in creating a jax.rs web service using maven? I think my problem has something to do with maven. Maybe I am using it wrong because when I create a jax.rs project not using Maven all works fine. I am using netbeans to run the service by the way. so I think i do not need the -0.0.1-SNAPSHOT part for now.

Comment: Do this. Create new project -> Maven -> Project From Archetype -> Search "jersey-quickstart-webapp" -> Select the grizzly one (not sun) -> Name the project. The result should be a webapp that can be run from a a servlet container like TomCat

Comment: You will notice that the app uses a `web.xml`. This is used instead of the `Application` subclass. You can use your `Application` subclass and get rid of the `web.xml` and it should still work.

Comment: A very strange thing is that it works in linux but not on windows!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have this in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```